# IE intstances is not working with protractor e2e

Tags: protractor, webdriver-manager

I have version :-
 protractor 5.4.2 
 webdriver-manager version is 12.1.7
angular 7.2.4

Steps to run our app on IE:

1. run webdriver-manager update --ie
    IEdriverserver.exe is 3.150.1 ,
    standalone service is 3.14.59 jar
    geckodriver-v0.26.0.exe
    chromedriver_79.0.3945.36.zip
2. run webdriver-manager start --ie
3. open another terminal and run ng e2e

   the error was:

   > Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
   >   i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
   >   [12:05:28] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
   >   [12:05:28] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
   >   [12:05:29] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://10.154.204.250:52076/wd/hub
   >   [12:05:29] E/launcher - Unable to create new service: InternetExplorerDriverService
   >   os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
   >   Driver info: driver.version: unknown
   >   [12:05:29] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: InternetExplorerDriverService

can you help me why I am receiving this error and how I can fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, take a minute and get used to the _markdown_ formatting.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and then [edit] your question accordingly to attract good answers.

Comment: There is also some missing information here, what is your config? Do the files exist in the webdriver-manager/selenium/ directory? What version of IE are you running? Have you looked if IE is still supported by selenium server 3.150.1?